# VBS Scripting.FileSystemObject Need help writing ANSI txt File

Tags: utf-8, vbscript, com, ansi

I am trying to create an ANSI file. But everything I try gives me an UTF-8 w/o BOM.

I have tried to do this with the least amount of code for testing purpose and this is what I found.

```
 Dim myFile 
 Dim objFSO : Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set myFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\TestFile.txt")
 myFile.Close
```

The above code gives me an ANSI file as advertised by MSDS but when i write to it in the bellow code

```
 Dim myFile 
 Dim objFSO : Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set myFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\TestFile.txt")
 myFile.WriteLine "TestLine"
 myFile.Close
```

When inspecting the file using Notepad++ now I have UTC-8 w/o BOM

There is code awaiting for the actual file I am trying to create. the code was not accepting the file. after some tedious debugging I found that it does not like the UTF format. If I save as ANSI using Notepad++ now the code accepts the file. I need to do this programmatically from the go.

Can anyone confirm if they get the same results? 
How do I make sure I end up with an ANSI text file?
Thank you

Comment: i am opening the resulting file with notepad++. There is a dependency on the actual file I am creating and it does not like the UTF format. If I convert the file to ANSI using notepad++ the code accepts the file. I could put screenshots if you want

Comment: What do you .WriteLine (instead of "TestLine") into myFile? Do you use "On Error Resume Next" in your 'real' code?

Comment: The file I am creating contains other file names that come from various test stations. The resulting files have symbols like degrees and various engineering symbols on their names. I am writing an interface in between 2 systems. I have no visibility of the code of the receiving end but after testing I found that when the file format is UTF as shown using Notepad++ it will reject the file. If I convert the same file to ANSI and retry feeding it to the receiving system it runs perfectly. I need the file to be ANSI and have the Engineering jargon on them.

Answer (score 3):

Common syntax: `object.CreateTextFile(filename[, overwrite[, unicode]])`. Here

- *overwrite*:
  Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether you can overwrite an existing file. The value is `true` if the file can be overwritten, `false` if it can't be overwritten. If omitted, existing files are not overwritten. **Note**:If the *overwrite* argument is `false`, or is not provided, for a filename that already exists, an **error** occurs.
- *unicode*:
  Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether the file is created as a Unicode or ASCII file. The value is `true` if the file is created as a Unicode file, `false` if it's created as an ASCII file. *If omitted, an ASCII file is assumed*. (but last statement seems to contradict your experience...)

So you could open your file with

```
Set myFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\TestFile.txt", true, false)
```

If it fails, use `object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])`, where

- *object*: Required. Object is always the name of a FileSystemObject.
- *filename*: Required. String expression that identifies the file to
  open.
- *iomode*:  Optional. Can be one of three constants: `ForReading`,
  `ForWriting`, or `ForAppending`.
- *create*: Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether a new file can
  be created if the specified filename doesn't exist. The value is `True`
  if a new file is created, `False` if it isn't created. If omitted, a
  new file isn't created.
- *format*:  Optional. One of three `TriState` values used to indicate the
  format of the opened file. If omitted, the file is opened as ASCII.

You could use literal values for `iomode`, `create` and `format` arguments, or define (and use) next constants:

```
'various useful constants
'iomode
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
'create
Const DontCreate =  False ' do not create a new file if doesn't exist
Const CreateFile =  True  ' create a new file if the specified filename doesn't exist
'format
Const OpenAsDefault = -2  ' Opens the file using the system default.
Const OpenAsUnicode = -1  ' Opens the file as Unicode.
Const OpenAsUSAscii =  0  ' Opens the file as ASCII.

'TriState (seen in documetation)
Const TristateUseDefault  = -2 ' Opens the file using the system default.
Const TristateTrue        = -1 ' Opens the file as Unicode.
Const TristateFalse       =  0 ' Opens the file as ASCII.
```

Then you could open your file with  (but ensure to delete existing one if exists!)

```
Set myFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( "C:\TestFile.txt", 2, true, 0)
```

or (more readable)

```
Set myFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( "C:\TestFile.txt" _
             , ForWriting, CreateFile, OpenAsUSAscii)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I tried this code but unfortunately for some reason. When I use the WriteLine method the file gets converted to UTF. the file remains ANSI as long as I don't write to it using WriteLine method.